# How do i create a argument at instantiation time

Tags: swift, arguments, instantiation

I have to "Create initializers in AppleDevice and iPad that will receive the arguments at instantiation time." . I don't understand what that means, can someone clarify it for me? What are arguments and instantiation time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that rather than using the default init method for the classes (AppleDevice and iPad in this case) you need to write another one that takes arguments.

For example:

```
class Person {
    var name: String?

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

So here we can see that `name` is the argument for the initialization of a Person.

We can define a variable with the type of person like this:

```
let someGuy: Person
```

But at this point, that variable hasn't been initialized yet. We can initialise it in this way:

```
someGuy = Person(name: "Joe")
```

I've separated it for a bit of clarity. We can do it in one line like this:

```
let someGuy = Person(name: "Joe")
```